# In a group $G$, prove the following result

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group in which $a^5=e$ and $aba^{-1}=b^m$ for some positive integer $m$, and some $a,b\in G$. Then prove that $b^{m^5-1}=e$.

**Progress** 
$$aba^{-1}=b^m\Rightarrow  ab^ma^{-1}=b^{m^2}$$
What will be the next?

Answer (score 6):

We have $$b=ebe=a^5ba^{-5}=a^4b^ma^{-4}=a^3b^{m^2}a^{-3}=a^2b^{m^3}a^{-2}=ab^{m^4}a^{-1}=b^{m^5}$$

Thus, multiplying by $b^{-1}$, we have $e=b^{m^5-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

You proved that
$$
b^{m^k} = a^k b a^{-k}
$$
(just expand $b^m$ in your formula for $b^{m^2}$, and use induction).
So,
$$b^{m^5-1}=b^{-1}b^{m^5}=b^{-1}a^5 b a^{-5} = b^{-1}ebe = e.$$